# Открытие файла

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, пишу событие, происходящее при нажатии кнопки...
Стандартно не могу открыть файл... Никак не записывается в поток:

```
  if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
  {
     if ( (fstream myStream(openFileDialog1->OpenFile())) != nullptr )
     {
        // Insert code to read the stream here.
        myStream.close();
     }
  }
```

Ну никак не работает...
Вот ошибки:

> `error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'myStream'
> 1>: error C3861: 'myStream': identifier not found
> 1>: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '!='
> 1>: warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
> 1>: error C2059: syntax error : ')'
> 1>: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
> 1>: error C2065: 'myStream' : undeclared identifier
> 1>: error C2228: left of '.close' must have class/struct/union`

Comment: Скажите, а пространство имен std объявлено? Похоже, что надо написать
std::fstream.
А еще похоже на наличие в коде непечатаемых символов.

Comment: Пространство обьявлено... какие символы???

Answer (score 3):

Может, не стоит объявлять переменную в if-е? Попробуйте так:

```
if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
{
    fstream myStream;
    if ( (myStream.open(openFileDialog1->OpenFile())) != nullptr )
    {
        // Insert code to read the stream here.
        myStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: А ничего, что fstream::open ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Виноват, соврал. Тогда myStream.open(openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) вызывать вне if, а в if проверять только myStream.

Comment: error C2664: 'void std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits>::open(const wchar_t *,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::IO::Stream ^' to 'const wchar_t *'

теперь такая ошибка..

Comment: OpenFile возвращает объект System::IO::Stream ^. Для того, чтобы извлечь из него имя файла используйте код вроде этого (пример из MSDN):<pre>
    if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() ==  System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
          {
             System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
                System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
             MessageBox::Show(sr->ReadToEnd());
             sr->Close();
          }</pre>

Comment: Вроде прошло успешно, сейчас поковыряюсь с условием, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что внутри if нельзя одновременно использовать объявление (fstream myStream) и выражение (в вашем случае сравнение на неравенство). Можно только одно из двух.

Решением, действительно, будет объявление переменной myStream до if.

Comment: не помогло...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
{
    fstream myStream;
    myStream.open(openFileDialog1->OpenFile())
    if ( myStream.is_open() )
    {
        // Insert code to read the stream here.
        myStream.close();
    }
}
```